# Files Ignored by .gitignore Still Staged: Seeking Resolution

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm facing an issue with my `.gitignore` file where certain directories within my `notebooks` folder are supposed to be ignored and not staged. Unfortunately, despite adding the corresponding entries to my `.gitignore`, the files from these directories, as well as the `README.md` file, are still being staged and tracked.

Here's what my `.gitignore` file looks like:

```
# Ignore README.md
README.md

# Ignore specific folders inside notebooks directory
notebooks/__pycache__/
notebooks/.ipynb_checkpoints/
notebooks/.Trash-0/
notebooks/.pytest_cache/
```

Despite these entries, files from the `__pycache__`, `.ipynb_checkpoints`, `.Trash-0`, and `.pytest_cache` directories, as well as the `README.md` file, are still showing up in my staged changes.

Here's the directory structure of my project:

```
.
├── .gitignore
├── README.md
├── notebooks
│   ├── Notebook.ipynb
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── .ipynb_checkpoints
│   ├── .Trash-0
│   └── .pytest_cache
└── other_files...
```

I've double-checked the paths, and they seem correct. Am I missing something? What could be causing this issue? Is there a workaround to ensure that these specific directories and the `README.md` file are truly ignored and not staged?

Answer (score 1):

If those files are tracked and committed *before* adding them to `.gitignore`, they'll still be tracked.

In order to ignore those previously-tracked files, you need to delete and commit the deleted files first. After that, if you add them again to the repo, they'll no longer be tracked.

So, if you still want them locally, just move them outside of your repo, commit the deleted change, and put them back in.